# python class init return dictionary values

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I would like to return a dictionary value when calling the object.

```
class card:
    foo={2:0}
def __init__(self,num):
    self._num=card.foo[num]
```

when I do

```
bar=card(2)
bar
```

it returns

```
<__main__.Card at 0x7f5d60440588>
```

how do I get it to return 0?

Comment: Seems strange. What is your goal?

Comment: You should use `get` to ensure a value.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi sometimes a `KeyError` is the right result!

Answer (score 1):

You have to extend the `__repr__` special method:

```
class Card:
    foo = {2: 0}

    def __init__(self,num):
        self._num = Card.foo.get(num)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self._num)
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't access to `_num` attribute of `bar`. You need use`bar._num`:

```
>>> class card:
...     foo={2:0}
...     def __init__(self,num):
...        self._num=card.foo[num]
... 
>>> bar=card(2)
>>> bar
<__main__.card instance at 0x7fa9d7f9c098>
>>> bar._num
0
```

> [*Attribute references*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) use the standard syntax used for all attribute references in Python: obj.name. Valid attribute names are all the names that were in the class’s namespace when the class object was created.

Answer (score 1):

Not allowed to comment, so I edit just one line in answer by @Malik Brahimi (`__repr__` and `__str__` should return string, not number):

```
class Card:
    foo = {2: 0}

    def __init__(self,num):
        self._num = Card.foo.get(num)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self._num)
```

Comment: That's not even true, why should we return a number as a string?

Comment: @Malik Brahimi: [__repr__()](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) says **The return value must be a string object**

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry if I forgot that. Please mark my solution as answer if you could.